# PrintPreviewController With large Images

Tags: .net, gdi+, print-preview

We use a `PrintPreviewControl` and draw to it's graphics object directly. Usually this consists of background images with other drawings on top.

This is working perfectly except when we are having to draw large background images. Large here refers to images of about 250 mb when converted to a bitmap.

When large images are drawn, everything works fine until we manually assign the `PrintDocument` a new `PrintPreviewController` so we can save the image (code below).

```
public Image MakeImage()
{
  PrintController oOriginalController = default(PrintController);
  PreviewPrintController oPreviewController = default(PreviewPrintController);
  Image oImage = default(Image);
  PreviewPageInfo[] oPageInfos = null;
  PreviewPageInfo oPageInfo = default(PreviewPageInfo);

  //Save the original controller
  oOriginalController = moPrintDocument.PrintController;

  //Create a preview controller
  oPreviewController = new PreviewPrintController();
  oPreviewController.UseAntiAlias = true;
  moPrintDocument.PrintController = new PrintControllerWithStatusDialog(oPreviewController);
  moPrintDocument.Print();

  //Get print pages
  oPageInfos = oPreviewController.GetPreviewPageInfo();
  if (oPageInfos.Length > 0)
  {
    //Get the page info
    oPageInfo = oPageInfos(0);

    //Set the image
    oImage = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(oPageInfo.PhysicalSize.Width / 100 * 96), Convert.ToInt32(oPageInfo.PhysicalSize.Height / 100 * 96));

    //Create the graphics object
    using (Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(oImage))
    {
      //Clear the image
      oGraphics.Clear(Color.White);

      //Draw the image
      oGraphics.DrawImage(oPageInfo.Image, 0, 0, oImage.Width, oImage.Height);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    //Set no image
    oImage = null;
  }

  //Restore the original controller
  moPrintDocument.PrintController = oOriginalController;

  //Return the pdf document
  return oImage;
}
```

The image that is created does not have the large images on it but it does have all other drawings.

When returning to the `PrintPreviewControl` only the first large image drawn shows up, all the other drawing is present.

This behaviour can only be reversed by re-starting our application.

Comment: Can you include some of your PrintPage code to make this issue reproducible?

Comment: @LarsTech - I can't easily provide the printing code, as it is very complex and would require our whole data structure. In essence two approx 8000 x 8000 px images are being drawn onto the graphics object followed by a few lines and polygons.

Comment: I tried sticking `e.Graphics.DrawImage(MakeImage(), Point.Empty);` in the PrintPage event, but it just recursed itself endlessly when it hit your `moPrintDocument.Print();` line.  Obviously, I can't do that.  I'll have to study this PrintPreviewController object.